# Remote LargeIcon using react-native-push-notification

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement react-native-push-notification with an ejected expo project.

The local notification with a payload like:

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
    id: '123', 
    ticker: "My Notification Ticker", 
    largeIcon: "ic_launcher", 
    smallIcon: "ic_notification", 
    bigText: "My big text that will be shown when notification is expanded", 
    subText: "This is a subText", 
    title: "My Notification Title",
    message: "My Notification Message"
});
```

works without any problem, both large icon and small icon are displayed correctly.

However, with a remote FCM like this:

```
{
    "to": "c23XFueEix0:APA91bFeZwGw5GnrGLdA5A56X9pRC6ag4_362rh7YbODv3ff-CKw3PZO6fr2HSEk3qUaMTwPMjBk6KLnqe_LuX0HHjIMC-0HT6mCu-_-udUhXAn-RViwMp00S_bMt4PBtAv38VnFmAL4",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Notification Heading Ready",
        "body": "Short Message Ready",
        "largeIcon": "ic_launcher", 
        "smallIcon": "ic_notification"
    }
}
```

Displays only the title and body, but not the icons. How can we send the icons?

Comment: do you have ic_launcher.png inside android/app/src/res/drawable or mipmap?

Comment: @Mervzs yes - it worked for local notification.

Comment: did you try to to use "icon" : "ic_launcher" on the payload of notification?

Comment: @Mervzs actually yes. 'icon' didn't do anything. Did it work for you?

Comment: i didn't tried that yet. but when I implemented fcm / notification I used react-native-firebase to set its small and large icon dynamically. https://rnfirebase.io/

Comment: and according to the docs of fcm http protocol. smallIcon and largeicon property is not part of notification payload support . https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: Maybe we send it as part of data? The package must have implemented a Notification Listener/Handler.